# Pytorch crossentropy loss with 3d input

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, cross-entropy

I have a network which outputs a 3D tensor of size `(batch_size, max_len, num_classes)`. My groud truth is in the shape `(batch_size, max_len)`. If I do perform one-hot encoding on the labels, it'll be of shape `(batch_size, max_len, num_classes)` i.e the values in `max_len` are integers in the range `[0, num_classes]`. Since the original code is too long, I have written a simpler version that reproduces the original error.

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
batch_size = 32
max_len = 350
num_classes = 1000
pred = torch.randn([batch_size, max_len, num_classes])
label = torch.randint(0, num_classes,[batch_size, max_len])
pred = nn.Softmax(dim = 2)(pred)
criterion(pred, label)
```

the shape of pred and label are respectively,`torch.Size([32, 350, 1000])` and `torch.Size([32, 350])`

The error encountered is

```
ValueError: Expected target size (32, 1000), got torch.Size([32, 350, 1000])
```

If I one-hot encode labels for computing the loss

```
x = nn.functional.one_hot(label)
criterion(pred, x)
```

it'll throw the following error

```
ValueError: Expected target size (32, 1000), got torch.Size([32, 350, 1000])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Pytorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html), `CrossEntropyLoss` expects the shape of its input to be `(N, C, ...)`, so the second dimension is always the number of classes. Your code should work if you reshape `preds` to be of size `(batch_size, num_classes, max_len)`.

Comment: Even if you one-hot encode the labels, it will throw an error when it is passed to the `CrossEntropyLoss`

Comment: Sorry, I think I found the problem and have updated my answer.